# How do I take screenshot in hyprland?

Tags: arch-linux, desktop-environment, wayland, screenshot

How do I take screenshot in Hyprland? I went through the [Hyprland Wiki](https://wiki.hyprland.org/FAQ/) but I am not able to get to take screenshots in my archlinux.

How do I solve this?

[How do I screenshot?](https://wiki.hyprland.org/FAQ/#how-do-i-screenshot)

[For a more complete utility, try our own screenshotting utility: Grimblast.](https://github.com/hyprwm/contrib)

Comment: why did you include the two links at the end of your post?

Comment: It would be much better next time to include description of what you already tried when you went through mentioned Wiki. What didn't work etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can install **Grimblast** utility from Hyprland's contrib, you linked in your own post. In Arch linux, you can use AUR package [grimblast-git](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages?O=0&K=grimblast-git). Install it with i.e. **yay**: `yay -S grimblast-git`.

### Screenshot area to clipboard

To take simple screenshot you can use i.e. `grimblast copy area` command, which will let you select region on your screen, take screenshot and copy it to clipboard.

### Screenshot area to file

If you want to save screenshot to file, you can do it with `grimblast save area /tmp/screenshot.png`.

### Other options

You can get all available options with command `grimblast usage`, for current version, it is:

```
Usage:
  grimblast [--notify] [--cursor] [--freeze] [--wait N] [--scale <scale>] (copy|save|copysave|edit) [active|screen|output|area] [FILE|-]
  grimblast check
  grimblast usage

Commands:
  copy: Copy the screenshot data into the clipboard.
  save: Save the screenshot to a regular file or '-' to pipe to STDOUT.
  copysave: Combine the previous 2 options.
  edit: Open screenshot in the image editor of your choice (default is gimp). See man page for info.
  check: Verify if required tools are installed and exit.
  usage: Show this message and exit.

Targets:
  active: Currently active window.
  screen: All visible outputs.
  output: Currently active output.
  area: Manually select a region or window.
```

### Shortcut from Hyprland

You can assign custom shortcut to take screenshot with *grimblast* in Hyprland. I.e for `SUPER + C` it would be:

```
bind = SUPER, C, exec, grimblast copy area
```